# Specific modal-backdrop customizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I can change the CSS for one of many modals in my page by setting as selector the id of that specific modal.

e.g.
instead:

```
.modal {
    top: 0px;
    margin-top: 240px;
    ...
}
```

setting

```
#my_modal {
    top: 0px;
    margin-top: 240px;
    ...
}
```

My question:

How can I change the css for only `#my_modal`'s corresponding `.modal-backdrop` element?

```
 $('.modal').addClass('my_personal_stuff');
```

works, while

```
 $('.modal-backdrop').addClass('my_personal_stuff');
```

doesn't works

Why the behavior is so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind the show and hide evento of your modal and add a class to .modal-backdrop div.

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oswaldoacauan/ZbsnJ/4/).

Javascript

```
function haveBackdrop() {
    if ($('.modal-backdrop').length > 0) {
        $('.modal-backdrop').addClass('my-modal-backdrop');
        clearTimeout(mBackdrop);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
var mBackdrop;

$('#myModal').on('show', function() {
    mBackdrop = setTimeout("haveBackdrop()", 100);
});
```

CSS

```
.my-modal-backdrop { /* your css backdrop modifications */ }
```

Comment: It doesn't works. Works perfectly for other elements - e.g. `$('.modal').addClass('my_modal_backdrop');`                             
but nothing happens when I try                             `$('.modal-backdrop').addClass('my_modal_backdrop');`                          Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

> How can I change the css for only #my_modal's corresponding
>   modal-backdrop?

```
// Add an extra class to the modal backdrop to make it customizable
$('.modal--custom').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.modal-backdrop').addClass('modal-backdrop--custom');
    });
});
```

This works for me. Check out this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3xoctkn/4/).